# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple (Python 3.11)

Tags: python, console-application, python-3.11

I am trying to create a noughts and crosses game in python, and I got an error in the bold text area in checkGridRow(). This is where I want to check if the game has been won by any player by checking for "XXX" or "OOO" in a horizontal row. At the end of the code, I use the parameter of "position" as the Y position in the grid and so pass 0, 1 and 2 to check all the rows. However I have run into the error in the title, and I don't know what it means despite searching, as I have no tuples in my code (as far as I can see). I am a beginner so please try to explain in relatively simple terms, thank you for helping

```
grid = [["_","_","_"],["_", "_", "_"],["_", "_", "_"]]
game = True


def checkGridRow(position):
    n = 0
    ***if grid[position,n]!= "_":***
        if grid[position,n]== grid[position,n+1] and grid[position,n+1]==grid[position,n+2]:
            game = False
    return game

def checkGridCol():
    tempList = ""
    c1 = [grid[0,0], grid[1,1], grid[2,2]]
    c2 = [grid[2,0], grid[1,1], grid[0,2]]
    if not any("_" in i for i in c1):
       for var in c1:
           tempList+= var
       if tempList == "XXX":
           game = False
       elif tempList == "OOO":
           game = False
    return game
            
        
def PlayerTurnX():
    column = int(input("enter column >> 1,2,3: "))
    column = column -1
    while str(column+1) not in "123":
        column = int(input("enter column 1,2,3: "))
        column = column-1
    
    row = int(input("enter row >> 1,2,3: "))
    row = row-1

    while str(row+1) not in "123":
        row = int(input("enter row >> 1,2,3: "))
        row= row-1


    
    if grid[row][column]=="_":
        grid[row][column] = "X"
    elif grid[row][column]!= "_":
        print("Space taken")
        row = int(input("enter row >> 1,2,3: "))
        row = row-1



    for item in grid:
        print(item[0]+" "+item[1]+" "+item[2])
    



def PlayerTurnO():
    column = int(input("enter column: >> 1,2,3: "))
    column = column-1
    while str(column+1) not in "123":
        column = int(input("enter column >> 1,2,3: "))
    
    row = int(input("enter row:  >> 1,2,3: "))
    row = row-1


    while str(row+1) not in "123":
         row = int(input("enter row:  >> 1,2,3: "))
         row = row-1

    if grid[row][column]=="_":
        grid[row][column] = "O"
    else:
        print("Space taken")
        column = int(input("enter column>> 1,2,3: "))
        column = column-1
        n=n-1



    for item in grid:
        print(item[0]+" "+item[1]+" "+item[2])



while game:
    print("Player X, your turn!")
    PlayerTurnX()
    checkGridRow(0)
    checkGridRow(1)
    checkGridRow(2)
    checkGridCol()
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Player O, your turn!")
    PlayerTurnO()
    checkGridRow(0)
    checkGridRow(1)
    checkGridRow(2)
    checkGridCol()
```

I've tried searching the error message and still cannot figure out where the tuple is, as far as I know tuples look like this `myTuple = (x, y, z)`

Answer (score 3):

`grid[position,n]` is not the correct syntax for accessing a nested list.

Use `grid[position][n]` instead.